# How can I configure an exception view in Pyramid for friendly error pages, but still pass errors through to a logger?

Tags: python, pyramid, sentry

I'm attempting to set up [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/) for my current web app. It can be [configured to act as a logger](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/pyramid.html#logger-setup).

However, I have an Exception view that looks like this:

```
@view_config(context=Exception,
             renderer='hitchedup:templates/errors/500.html')
def error_view(exc, request):
    """Display a friendly error message"""
    return {}
```

The idea is that whenever any exception occurs on the site, I can deliver a friendly message to the user.

But, how do I still pass the errors through to the logger? Right now, the Exception view catches all exceptions, but then they never reach the logger.

I tried raising and catching `exc` inline in the Exception view, then sending it to Sentry through the client directly, but then I don't get the full stacktrace I would get if I caught the exception where it was originally raised.

How can I get both friendly 500 pages and still have good logging and error reporting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bare `raise` keyword is the ticket.

Instead of using logging, capture the Exception in a view with a friendly message. Then, use `raise` without an argument, which raises the original exception. Catch the exception and use the Sentry client to capture it and pass it along.

The final view looks like this:

```
from raven.base import Client
from pyramid.view import view_config


@view_config(context=Exception,
             renderer='hitchedup:templates/errors/500.html')
def error(context, request):
    """Display an error message and record it in Sentry."""
    client = Client()
    try:
        raise
    except Exception:
        client.captureException()
    return {}
```